# Media IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi when I tried to use this piece of code:

```
    import media

toy_story = media.Movie("Toy Story","A story of a boy and his toys come to life","http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Toy_Story.jpg","https://www,youtube.com/watch?v=vwyZH85NQC4")
print(toy_story.storyline)
```

The directory for media and this file is: `C:\Users\Lukes\Desktop\media`

The code for media is here:

```
class Movie():
def __init__(self, movie_title, movie_storyline, poster_image, trailer_youtube):
    self.title = movie_title
    self.storyline = movie_storyline
    self.poster_image_url = poster_image
    self.trailer_youtube_url = trailer_youtube
```

and whenever I try to run `entertainment_center.py`

it comes out with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lukes/Desktop/media/entertainment_center.py", line 1, in <module>
    import media
  File "C:/Users/Lukes/Desktop/media\media.py", line 2
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Why does your `import` have an indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `__init__` is with the class scope.  Indent it to consider that.

```
class Movie(object):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.id = 0
```

Plus, don't indent the top `import` instruction in the first file.